# Wien on Temperature and Entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, thermal-radiation, specific-reference

As far as I understand, Wien defines entropy, which he uses in his derivation, as

$$   S = \text{v} \int\limits_0^{\infty}  \varphi(\rho, \nu) d \nu,   $$

where $\text{v}$ is the volume occupied by the radiation, $\nu$ is the frequency of that radiation, $\rho(\nu)$ is the radiation density and $\varphi$ is a function of the variables $\rho$ and $\nu$.

Unfortunately, I can't find an English translation of his seminal paper

> Wien, W., "Temperatur und Entropie der Strahlung", Ann. Phys. Chem., 52, 132-165 (1894),

where he has developed his ideas on the matter. I would appreciate it if someone who has dealt with this problem could shed some light on this important derivation and/or possibly give a link to an English translation or perhaps a translation in Russian of the paper.

ANSWER:

One can at once see how this integral can be entropy by considering $\varphi = \frac{\rho(\nu)}{T}$, where $\rho(\nu)$ is radiation density. So, then, we will have

$$  \text{v} \int\limits_0^{\infty} \varphi(\rho, \nu) d\nu = \frac{\text{v}}{T} \int\limits_0^{\infty} \rho(\nu) d\nu = \frac{U}{T} = \frac{Q}{T} = S$$

because the process is isochoric.

Unfortunately the above formula for $S$ cannot be used to recover the II law for an isochoric process

$$\frac{dS}{dU} = \frac{1}{T},$$

so $S_\nu$ must be used, expressing the entropy for a given frequency and not over all frequencies as in the integral shown in the OP, which I don't believe Wien used in any of his works (unless, someone can show otherwise).

Comment: Could you say the page of the original paper you are looking at? I can’t seem to find the entropy equation you mention.

Comment: That's the problem. I just guessed that the definition in question of \(S\) might be in that paper but I can't find it in English (or Russian) to see. It very well may be that said definition is in some other of Wien's papers. I wasn't able to find Wien's Collected Works either, if such collection exists at all put together.

Comment: Okay, when you say 'this important derivation', the derivation of which law?

Comment: Wien's blackbody radiation law in the form $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \rho}  = \frac{1}{T}$. Where in Wien's works and how is this expression shown to be connected with his law?

Comment: Hi @ganzewoort. An answer should be in an answer; not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you started to think of radiation in a closed volume like   gas molecules and apply the  ideal gas law to the radiation photons you might get a start on how to derive the  origin of the expression you are querying. I remember some time ago reading that was how Wien derived the formula.

Comment: I don't believe Wien used that definition of entropy anywhere in his works.

Comment: To ganzewoort: how did you make out pv\T where p(v) =radiation density is an entropy expression? Should it not be V(PV?)/T